# How can i partially hide text vertically in html

Tags: html, css

This is the image of the half hidden text from a website called sounddrown
[image: sound drown]

I am trying to replicate the half hidden behavior of the sounddrown text. It doesn't seem to be a picture. Here is the full [website](http://soundrown.com).

Comment: Show us your code, rather than external links.

Comment: its not my code i am trying to replicate the behaviour.but i cant seem to make heads or tails of it.please help

Comment: Then show your own code to what you've done... we're not here to do it for you...

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element from your browser?

Comment: i am still learning html. to reinforce what i learn i have been studying websites.and trying to understand what makes them tick. I just came across this website and saw the half hidden behaviour of the text.i clicked inspect element to check out the html and css but i couldnt understand this particular behaviour.please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you've tried to solve the problem but your solution doesn't work, it's much easier for us to debug that than it start from scratch. Plus, you'll learn more by doing it that way, too!

Comment: My suggestion is this. Inspect the element of interest and the elements around it. In this specific case you just need to inspect two divs (`#mainlogo` and its inner div (which contains the text)). And try deactivating rules until the observed behavior goes away. Try to minimize the rules required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```css
.topDiv div{
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    top: 6px;
}
.topDiv{
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="topDiv">
<div>
 Your Text
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to do this in a photo editor, however, with CSS and JS, you can do some amazing things, overflow:hidden property is your best friend.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Check the Link to the pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/Wxkpyz

Hover over the elements, there is much more cool options there, I will actually make some cool effects right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firefox or chrome you can right click on parts of a site and press inspect, which will show you the HTML and CSS of the site and you can inspect certain bits to see how it's done.

```css
#mainlogo {
  height: 24px;
  font-family: 'Gudea', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#mainlogo div {
  z-index: 200;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainlogo">
  <div>SOUNDROWN</div>
</div>
```

This is how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div>Your Text</div>
```